# How to group an SQL date column stored as int as Year Month using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a column in SQL with a date value (CreDt) stored as an int.

the below Linq2Sql query syntax will group my table by the CreDt date. i.e 20220109 which is not what I want, I want to group it by Year or by YearMonth. i.e 202201

how can I do that?

```
var yymm = from p in Order
              group p by new { ym = p.CreDt } into d
              select new { YearMonth = d.Key.ym};
```

Comment: Divide the date by 100, so the day will be truncated due to integer division. `group p by new { ym = p.CreDt / 100 } into d`

Comment: if you have an answer why don't you just answer the question @AndrewWilliamson ?

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu it's a suggestion, not an answer. I know how this will behave in C#, but I'm not sure of the results when translated to SQL, or if it will actually translate

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or Linq2SQL?

Comment: I am using Linq2SQL

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson thanks, works fine. you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropping digits from a number is easy, just divide the date by 100 when you group. The day will be truncated due to integer division.

```
20220109 / 100 = 202201.09
               = 202201

group p by new { ym = p.CreDt / 100 } into d
```

If you want to group by year, divide by 10000.

Comment: Ah I missed the *"stored as an int"* bit in the OP, as unsurprisingly, it's not something that is normally recommended